# Typescript compilation depends on order of files

Tags: javascript, compilation, typescript

I'm developing typescript library and I want to use it in my web application.

I would like to compile all library files into single library.js file.

I tried to use ts compiler with tsconfig.json file as well as compiling with gulp task but I have issues with class order in output file in both cases.

Also generated code has lots of IIFE

```
var MyLibrary;
(function (MyLibrary) {
.....
})(MyLibrary || (MyLibrary = {}));
```

I guess it should be there just once, not for each class, right?

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "amd",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "outFile": "dist/js/floor-map-designer.js",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "src/app.ts"
  ]
}
```

and gulp tasks config:

```
var tsProject = ts.createProject({
    declarationFiles: true,
    noExternalResolve: false,
    module: 'AMD',
    removeComments: true,
    outFile: "my-library.js",
    exclude: ["app.ts", "config.ts"]
});

var paths = {
    npm: './node_modules/',
    lib: "./lib/vendor/",
    tsSource: ['./src/MyLibrary/**/*.ts', "./lib/typings/tsd.d.ts"],
    tsOutput: "./dist/js/",
    tsDef: "./lib/typings/"
};

gulp.task('ts-compile', function () {
    var tsResult = gulp.src(paths.tsSource)
                    .pipe(ts(tsProject));

    return merge([
        tsResult.dts.pipe(gulp.dest(paths.tsDef)),
        tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest(paths.tsOutput))
    ]);
});
```

I remember last time I used TypeScript I used to create autogenerated reference file with lots of

```
/// <reference path="...."
```

and add 
`/// <ts:autoRef="referencesFile.ts">` to all .ts files.

But I have noticed TS compiler should not depend on file order anymore and my IDE doesn't require it anymore, so I would like to avoid it if possible.

I also noticed using --out option is considered bad (at least according to this website: https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md) but how to replace it?

I'm using Typescript 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

> I also noticed using --out option is considered bad (at least according to this website: https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md) but how to replace it?

Use modules : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

In your case change :

```
module: 'AMD',
removeComments: true,
outFile: "my-library.js",
```

to

```
module: 'amd',
removeComments: true,
```

And use a module loader (for amd that would be requirejs http://requirejs.org/)

Comment: OK, I will try it. Does it mean I will have to add import even for internal module dependencies? Example: class A extends B  - do I have to import B?

Comment: Yes. If you don't then you have to manage the ordering yourself in a manner that is disconnected from the actual source (e.g. files array , reference file hacks etc)

Comment: Thanks for advice,  I tried to use RequireJS and AMD modules, but it doesn't work very well for me. RequireJS seems to be very buggy in Google Chrome (it doesn't even load the data-main file when developer console is open). And I would strongly prefer having my library concatenated into one file. I guess it would be OK for me to load that concatenated file using requireJS, but I don't want to load every single class and interface.